# Arduino Not Uploading Program to Kit

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have a Boarduino Duemilanove w/Atmega 328. I want to upload my program to it.  I have W8.1 on my laptop.

The power green led is running and the red led is blinking. When I put the serial cable, but before I upload my program, the arduino.exe gives me the message:

> "Arduino: 1.6.5 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino Duemilanove or
>   Diecimila, ATmega328"

and

> Sketch uses 1,030 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is
>   30,720 bytes. Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory,
>   leaving 2,039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.

and then

> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\.\COM2": Access is denied.
>   Problem uploading to board.  See
>   http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
>   This report would have more information with "Show verbose output
>   during compilation"   enabled in File > Preferences."

anyone can help me please?.

Answer (score 1):

I know this one is old but i had the same problem and for me it ended up being the cable. I found a smaller one to do the upload and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In the IDE, go to tools > board, then select your board. After that, you go to tools > port, and select the serial port or USB port the Arduino is hooked up to. If you are using a mac, the port name should be long, so look for USB in the name. On windows, it should say either COM5// or COM6// or something similar. If not, just play around with different ports and boards (in the ide selection) and see if one of the combinations works. You shouldn't need to play around with the board selection too much, but try different ports. One is bound to work.